# MySQL not updating a number if the change is very small

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x

When I update a number with a long SQL query, when I update a number with a small change, it doesn't change in the database. I use Python with mysqlclient 1.4.4. Why is that?

This is the query:

```sql
UPDATE 
  listing_field_changes 
SET 
  prospectus_url=NULL, 
  revenue_gross=1784063, 
  currency=0, 
  entry_id='13560', 
  last_update='2021-02-23 19:51:12.930817' 
WHERE 
  listing_id = 8562
```

The field that doesn't change is `revenue_gross`. It's initially 1784060 and becomes 1784063. The query doesn't show any error in PHPMyadmin. It updates 1 row but sometimes it updates 0 rows.

`revenue_gross` data type in the database is `float`.

Comment: I'm guessing you can simplify the query in your code so it is simpler and still captures your issue.  With your level of reputation, you should also be able to format it reasonably.

Comment: What is the number you're updating here that doesn't really change? What's the `CREATE TABLE` for the table?

Comment: What is the change? What is the structure of your table? If your use of Python is actually relevant to your question, where is the relevant Python code?

Comment: Please clarify "*it doesn't change in the database*".  Does the query fail with an error?  Any warnings?  Does it work if you execute the query directly in mysql client?  How are you inspecting the database to establish whether it has changed?  Are the update/read operations in the same session or could there be a concurrency/transaction isolation issue between them?

Comment: "The field (...) revenue_gross (...) becomes 1784063" -- And 1784063 is exactly the value you set it to in the `UPDATE`. So everything works as it should...

Comment: "It updates 1 row but sometimes it updates 0 rows." How often do you execute the update? Do you allways restore the database to the initial state before executing the statement? I can't figure out what is meant with "sometimes".

Comment: Guys, I found the answer, but I can't answer it here because it is closed. It's a bug in mysql. I should set the field as double instead of float

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. The table structure for revenue_gross use float. It turns out there is a bug with float type in Mysql. I changed it to double and it is fixed